# Files getting deleted mysteriously from the Documents Folder

Tags: ios, ipad

We have an iOS application for the iPad that is having strange behavior. We store the state of the app in an XML file in the documents folder. Every once in a while our testers are reporting that when the application crashes the file on the disk gets deleted as well. This is very strange, since I can't figure out what can be causing this. Any pointers to how I can debug this issue.

The problem is complicated by the fact that this happens randomly and only on certain ipads(generally iPad2).  We are using NSData initWithcontentOfFile.

By any chance can this be related to memory mapping of the files.

Comment: What did you do to save data to file? I guess that everything is still in memory, not saved to file yet.

Comment: If the file was there at some point. It might be that you saved wrong data to that file, and so it became 0 bytes.

Comment: @iBasel if it becomes 0 bytes, would I still see the file on disk? This one just clean disappeared.

Comment: This happened to me with a png file, and the file was still on disk with 0 bytes. I'm not sure about XML. Check the data you write to that file every time on [NSData writeToFile:]

Comment: Hi iBasel, your answer basically gave me an insight which helped solve the problem. The issue was not with NSData write but in the way we created the filenames. We used a sequence number to store filenames and the sequence number was stored using NSUserDefaults, which should write to disk periodically but if the app crashes it might not. What then happens is that when the user creates a new file it uses the previous sequence number and overwrote the old file which to the testers looked like the file got deleted. Thanks a lot for getting my grey cell working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are writing atomically

Comment: [xmlData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil]; this is how we are writing. But the problem is not the writing. The files gets deleted when the app crashes randomly.

Comment: hmm, I assume you're writing to the documents folder (or a sub folder thereof)? Is it crashing when reading the file?